# NGINX HTTP redirect to HTTPS fails: Invalid number of arguments in "return" directive

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

When I am trying to run the following host.conf with command "nginx -c /etc/nginx/conf/host.conf" it fails. I got error

```
Error: 

[emerg] 1#1: invalid number of arguments in "return" directive in /etc/nginx/conf/host.conf:54
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "return" directive in /etc/nginx/conf/host.conf:54
```

host.conf:

```
stream {   

    upstream test {
        server 110.10.0.1:4000;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass test;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

I am using nginx:1.17.10 and have no idea why this is not working. Any idea?

Comment: You have mixed up the `return` directive from the stream module with the `return` directive from the `http` module. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_return_module.html#return).

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith for the answer. Is there a way to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS in stream module?

Comment: Or can I use the both modules at the same time?

Comment: In my case I forgot the semicolon at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

you can add http module, example

```
stream {   

    upstream test {
        server 110.10.0.1:4000;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass test;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }
}

http {
   server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
}
```

This work for me